# Express module error while listening http server in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a nodejs http server

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function start(route, handle){
    function onRequest(request,response){
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
        route(handle, pathname, response, request);
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started");
    app.listen(8888);
    console.log('Express app listening on port 8888');
}
```

it gives error

```
f:\Labs\nodejs\webapp>node index.js
Server has started
Express app listening on port 8888

events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:769:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:909:14)
    at listen (net.js:936:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:985:5)
    at Function.app.listen (f:\Labs\nodejs\webapp\node_modules\express\lib\appli
cation.js:532:24)
    at Object.start (f:\Labs\nodejs\webapp\server.js:15:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (f:\Labs\nodejs\webapp\index.js:11:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

when i change the port of app.listen it dont throw this error, what can be done?

will changing port other than server port will keep the session of the server on another port??

and how can i access this app variable in other js page to get/set the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple things listening on the same port like this, hence the `EADDRINUSE` error.  If you want to create your own http server while using Express, you can do it like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(8888);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

From the Express docs:

> The app returned by express() is in fact a JavaScript Function,
>   designed to be passed to node's http servers as a callback to handle
>   requests.

Or you can just do

```
app.listen(8888);
```

And then Express will setup an `http` server for you.

You would then set up your routes in Express to actually handle requests coming in. With Express, routes look like this:

```
app.get('/foo/:fooId', function(req, res, next) {
   // get foo and then render a template
   res.render('foo.html', foo);
});
```

If you want to access your `app` in other modules (usually for testing) you can just export it like any other variable:

```
module.exports.app = app;
```

You'll then be able to `require('./app').app` in other modules.

Comment: And then Express will setup an http server for you.
this line actually solved my problem, I didnt knew express creates another server for it. so actually problem was that, i was unintentionally creating 2 servers on same port, which was causing exception. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure if you actually needed to setup your own http server instance (this is useful if you will be handling http and https connections).  If you don't need to, just use `app.listen` - much easier :)

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to run on the same port, you can see if you have currently running node processes with

`ps aux | grep node`

and then `kill -9 PROCESSID`